# RxJs simplify repeated pluck + flatMap

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Starting from an object like this:

```
const business = {
  id: "1a2b3c",
  accounts: [
    {
      name: "Pizza Express",
      stores: [
        { id: "5", webSite: "www.pizza-ny.com" },
        { id: "6", webSite: "www.pizza-la.com" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Expected output:
A stream of *Stores* (not an array of Stores)

[image]

My attempt:

```
return business.pipe(
  pluck("accounts"),
  flatMap(val => val),
  pluck("stores"),
  flatMap(val => val)
);
```

This works but, for me, the operators seem like repetitive and I'm wondering if I can simplify them. Also tried with the common `map` but I can't get it.

For example:

```
return business.pipe(
  pluck("accounts"),
  map(val => val.stores)
);
```

I don't understand why this returns `undefined`. I get an array of `accounts` and then projecting the `stores` property of each one... I guess I'm misunderstanding something.

Do you see a simpler or more elegant approach?

Comment: `mergeMap(b => [].concat(...b.accounts.map(a => a.stores)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be some duplication in your operators since you are reaching into nested objects for nested arrays. There is probably a way to write a nice custom operator (maybe I'll look into that if I have time), but I think the simplest way is to use just the [mergeMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap) (same thing as `flatMap`).

It will look something like this (edited to filter out accounts without stores – credit to Picci's comment)

```
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { mergeMap, filter } from "rxjs/operators";

of(business)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(b => b.accounts),
    /* filter out accounts that don't have stores */
    filter(a => !!a.stores),
    mergeMap(a => a.stores)
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);

/** console output:
 * 
 * { id: "5", webSite: "www.pizza-ny.com" }
 * { id: "6", webSite: "www.pizza-la.com" }
 */
```

Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-njvj7q?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts

Side note: you could even use [switchMap()](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) instead of `mergeMap()`. Since you are dealing with observables that complete, there isn't much difference between which one you use.

#### EDIT (explanation for `map` differences)

The reason your map() isn't working is because you are trying to access .stores on an array, not an object:

```
return business.pipe(
  pluck("accounts"), // accounts is an array
  map(val => val.stores) // `accounts[0].stores` would return a value for you
);
```

`map` works differently between `Array.prototype.map()` and RxJS `map()` because RxJS has a different implementation.

In plain JavaScript [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a function *on an array* and will return *a new array*. The key there is it is *always* array based. From the docs (emphasizes added):

> The `map()` method creates a *new array* populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the *calling array*.

In RxJS [map()](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) is an operator that is applied to *any value* inside an Observable. It is not guaranteed to be an array so it does not iterate over the value. RxJS `map()` is taking the value *inside* of an Observable and "mapping" it to a new structure/value. From the docs (emphasizes added):

> Applies a given `project` function to *each value* emitted by the source Observable, and emits the resulting *values as an Observable.*

Comment: I just noticed that. Learned something new! I will update my answer.

Comment: I'm adding here the same doubt I expressed to Picci. Wow, I understand why `val.stores` returns `undefined`, but don't understand why `val` is an array. So, `pluck("accounts")` returns an array of accounts, isn't it? Then, if I applied `map()` (of normal Array, not RxJS) on an array, I would be able to iterate over all the accounts and get the stores property. Why here is not the same?

Comment: I edited my answer to add more clarification on the differences between `array.map()` and RxJS `map()` operator.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, what you want to achieve is to create an Observable that emits, as a stream, each `store` of all the `accounts`.

So one way could be this

```
business.pipe(  // business is assumed to be an Observable that emits the business Object you describe in your question
  map(b => b.accounts),
  mergeMap((accounts) => accounts),
  mergeMap(account => account.stores)
)
```

At the end of the day it is not much different from your solution.

The reason why your last snippet does not work is explained in the comments I have added to your code below.

```
return business.pipe(
  // With `pluck(accounts)` you extract the `accounts` property of the `business` object.
  // Such property is an `array` of accounts. 
  pluck("accounts"),
  // Now you want to map the `stores` property of `val`, but `val` is an array 
  // and an array has not `stores` property, so you get `undefined`
  map(val => val.stores)
);
```

Comment: Wow, I understand why `val.stores` returns `undefined`, but don't understand why `val` is an array. So, `pluck("accounts")` returns an array of accounts, isn't it? Then, if I applied `map()` (of normal Array, not RxJS) on an array, I would be able to iterate over all the accounts and get the stores property. Why here is not the same?

Comment: Because the rxjs operator `map` and the array method `map` are 2 different things, sharing just the name. So you have both of them in the same line of code like this `map(val => val.map(account => // do stuff with the account))`, where the inner `map` is the array method and the external one is the rxjs operator.

Comment: Ok, I'll review that. Also, do you know think this is a good way of handling `stores: null` cases? Modifying the second `mergeMap` like this: `mergeMap(a => a.stores || empty()),`. And even adding a new line `filter(val => val)` to not return `null` values inside the `stores` array.

Comment: I would add a `filter(account => !!account.stores)` between the first and the second `mergeMap` to remove all accounts which have no stores.